# Is WPA2(PKS) AES vulnerable to 4 way hand shake and brute force attack?

Tags: wpa2-psk

I can easily crack a WPA TKIP using a dictionary/brute force method, provided that I collect the four way handshake. Is the same method possible on WPA2 AES? I cannot find any articles about '4 way handshake capture' and 'WPA2 AES cracking' together; but I was able to use aircrack-ng to crack my WPA2 AES wireless network.

Does WPA2 AES uses uses the same method as TKIP where using a 4 way handshake a temporary password is generated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Both WPA-TKIP and WPA2-AES use the same 4-way handshake, and the same way of deriving the PTK from the PSK. AES does not affect this. To launch the brute-force attack on the PSK you only need to capture the 4-way handshake (including the nonces). This is also true for WPA2-AES-PSK.